# Ubuntu never finishing suspend, manually turned off power, next restart will not finish, what should I do?

Tags: boot, suspend

I tried to put my Ubuntu 16.04 into suspend mode, it never finish it.

Then I manually turned off the power. Next, I turned on the power, the booting stalls at with the following displayed:

```
rootNew: clean, 705452/12829104 files, 7777458/51195904 blocks
```

where `rootNew` is the partition for the root '/'

what is the best that I should do to get out of this panic state, and resume to working condition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I recovered, by booting into recovery mode, and using fsck from the recover menu to clean the file system.

It's indeed due to corrupted boot file system, fsck there found the corruption, and cleaned it, then it was possible to resume normal reboot.